# Laravel passport installation error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I've just downloaded the latest laravel 5.3 and I'm trying to install passport, but I'm getting the following composer error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - laravel/passport v2.0.0 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0].
        - laravel/passport v2.0.1 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0].
        - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/http v5.4.0
        - Installation request for laravel/passport ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v2.0.0, v2.0.1].


    Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

**Composer .json file** 
http://pastebin.com/ne4RkL96

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happens, because after releasing Laravel 5.4, this package also had been updated to v 2.0 and requires Laravel 5.4. But you are using Laravel 5.3. Try to install earlier version:

```
composer require laravel/passport ^v1
```

Also, you can learn about the versions of this package here:

[Laravel Passport](https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/passport#v2.0.1)

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 5.3.

In your `composer.json` file put `"laravel/passport": "~1.0"` and  run "composer update" command.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

In line with Rashad's answer as it helped me out, you need a version of passport less than major version 2. This can be accomplished with several version strings `^v1`, `v1.x`, `>= 1 < 2` and several other combinations.

I used this: `php composer.phar require laravel/passport ^v1` and it worked awesomely.

Answer (score 1):

Install laravel passport version 7:

```
> composer require laravel/passport:7.5.1
```